# Iframe Url Decoding confused

Tags: javascript, urlencode, urldecode

It's used in some site.. to hide iframe src url

```
String.prototype.edoceD = function () {
    var x = this.length;
    var edoceD = "";
    while (x>=0) {
      edoceD = edoceD + this.charAt(x);
      x--;
    }
    return edoceD;
  }

var OLID = 'a66793a78396b6d6a6d6c6b61746'
    OLID = OLID.edoceD()
```

Result of this OLID ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The function you have provided will just reverse the string.

Comment: Thank. Got the Result. I try Online reverse as u told and got the desired Output..